# N:N Entity Framework C# Relationship

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having a problem with many-to-many relationships in a pizzeria system I'm developing.

I have an entity called "Payament" that has a list of Pizzas and a list of Drinks.

ex:

```
public class Payament
{
    
    public string? PayamentId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }

    public string? CPFId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Client? Client { get; set; }

    public double? TotalPay { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTransaction { get; set; }

    public virtual StatusOrder StatusOrder { get; set; }

    public Payament()
    {
        Pizzas = new List<Pizza>();
        Drinks = new List<Drink>();
        DateTransaction = DateTime.Now;
        StatusOrder = StatusOrder.CARRINHO;
    }

    
}
```

Also, I have two entities Pizza and Drink.

ex:

```
public class Pizza : IItem
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Payament> Payament { get; set; }

    public Pizza()
    {
        Payament = new List<Payament>();
    }

}


 public class Drink : IItem
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Payament> Payament { get; set; }

    public Drink()
    {
        Payament = new List<Payament>();
    }
    
}
```

These classes are configured as many-to-many in OnModelCreating()...
Drink:

```
builder.HasMany(h => h.Payament)
            .WithMany(d => d.Drinks);
```

Pizza:

```
builder.HasMany(h => h.Payament)
            .WithMany(p => p.Pizzas);
```

Payament:

```
builder.HasMany(p => p.Pizzas) 
            .WithMany(p => p.Payament);

        builder.HasMany(d => d.Drinks)
            .WithMany(d => d.Payament);
```

Migrations were generated, all right. But when I go to send a payment, I get this error:

MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pizzaroller`.`drinkpayament`, CONSTRAINT `FK_DrinkPayament_Payament_PayamentId` FOREIGN KEY (`PayamentId`) REFERENCES `payament` (`PayamentId`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

What I believe it could be:
If I'm not mistaken, a drinkpayament table and a pizzapayament table are created where the primary keys between the relations are joined.

And in this case, "Payament" has a primary key of type string, while items "Pizza" and "Drink" have a primary key of type int.

The conflict is likely to be found in this divergence. I could be wrong, of course.
So I would like to know how I can solve this problem. And also, if possible, tips on how I can work with existing items for sale and relate them to a payment.

Project is on github if you want to take a look:
https://github.com/newhobbye/pizza-roller-api

This project is for the exercise of knowledge and some patterns that I will implement to practice. I accept any kind of criticism! A big hug and many thanks!

Comment: With EF Core we have been defining our bridge tables explicitly. Earlier versions you had to do that.  What version of EF Core are you using?  Implicit tables hide some magic anyways, it feels more natural to write those out.

Comment: Unrelated: `public double? TotalPay { get; set; }` do not use floating point types for monetary amounts.

Comment: [Relationship Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) Under the header "Join Entity Type Configuration" looks like they added a method `.UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("JoinTable"));`  I don't want to add it as an answer since I haven't tried it, but it looks promising.

Comment: You're missing your one side with the many-to-many in your modelbuilder. I would scaffold the existing db and see what is generated. That should help you find the issue.

Comment: @FelixCastor I'm using EF Core 6.0

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer. Mount an existing db? @GH DevOps

Comment: See this link...point to your existing db and have EF generate your classes and dbcontext for you. Compare your class with the scaffold class to see the differences. Code first sucks, I just removed it from my project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: Thank you friend! I will read this documentation and try to find the solution. @GH DevOps

Comment: YW. It's easier to do it in SQL than in code. When I got stuck, I would do the db changes in Management Studio, scaffold those changes and then change my code. The new EF by default uses junction tables implicitly. I'd rather create classes instead.

Comment: Please don't link to external sources to share code. A question should contain all essential code in the text itself. Here the actual code throwing the exception is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve.

I was resending the client entity in update. And I hadn't turned off the AsNoTracking() option;

In addition to this problem, I was also resending the items instead of associating the existing ones by id.

Thank you all for your help!